# pass object between forms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a form application that has two windows. In the main window, Form1 I create an instance of the class Treatment. I would like to pass that instance, once a image is clicked to the other window form2. So far I have:
Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private Treatment treatment;

//method where i inistantiate the treatment
private void processTreatment(int id, Button button)
    {
        treatment = new Treatment(wirelessResult, id);
        Alarm alarm = new Alarm(count, treatment);
        wirelessResult.GenerateNumber();
        alarm.setColor();
        events.add(alarm);
        if (getResult(treatment) == true)
        {
            storeSuccess(button);  
        }
        else if (getResult(treatment) == false)
        {
            storeFailed(button);
        }
    }
// image clicked   
private void treatmentStation1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Form2 secondForm = new Form2(treatment);
        secondForm.Show();
    }
```

and in form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Treatment treatment;


    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public Form2(Treatment treatment)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.treatment = treatment;
    }
  }
}
```

I get 1 error : Error   1   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'WasteTreatment.Treatment' is less accessible than method 'WasteTreatment.Form2.Form2(WasteTreatment.Treatment)'

Someone can help me to fix this?

Comment: Make your Treatment class public

Comment: @YograjGupta: That may not be the ideal solution, but it will correct the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`private Treatment treatment` can only be used within `Form1`, because you have marked it `private`.

I think the best way to correct the problem is something like this:

```
Form2 secondForm = new Form2(new Treatment(wirelessResult, id));
```

and you can make `wirelessResult` and `id` private members of `Form1`.

Comment: hi Thank you for the answer, it might have fix my first problem but now I have another error Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'WasteTreatment.Treatment' is less accessible than method 'WasteTreatment.Form2.Form2(WasteTreatment.Treatment)' is it related to my Treatment class?

Comment: Your `Treatment` class (wherever it is) needs to be declared `public`.

Comment: Yes I have done that and now it looks like it is working, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The inconsistent accessibility means that you the `WasteTreatment.Treatment` class is not visible to `Form2`.

For example, if `Form2` is in `AssemblyA` and `WasteTreatment.Treatment` in `AssemblyB` and `WasteTreatment.Treatment` is marked as `internal`, which a class w/o a modifier will by default be.  `Form2` would not be able to use `WasteTreatment.Treatment`

Without seeing that class, all I can say is try making the class `public` and see if that works.  Another way to resolve the issue is if `WasteTreatment.Treatment` implements an interface have `Form2` accept the interface instead of the concrete object, and make sure the interface is marked as `public` as well.

Comment: namespace WasteTreatment
{
    class Treatment
    {
       private Boolean finalStatus;
       private WirelessTreatmentResult result;
       private int id;
       private string name;

Comment: @lucaConfa The class by default is internal, try `public class Treatment { .... }`

Comment: sorry,  I wanted just to show you the treatment class, not sure I know what is assemblyA and assemblyB. All classes are in the same namespace. Does it help?

Comment: @lucaConfa Do the classes belong to different projects or the same project?